# Is there an idiomatic equivalent in Spanish for “to have other fish to fry”

Tags: traducción, modismos

Is there an idiomatic equivalent in Spanish for “to have other fish to fry”?

> have other fish to fry: "To have more important things to do"

In the two romance languages I am familiar with, this idiom is related to cats:

In French: *avoir d'autres chats à fouetter* - to have other cats to whip 
In Italian: *avere altre gatte da pelare* - to have other cats to skin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of anything else than the literal to "to have more important things to do":

> "Tener cosas más importantes que hacer"

The fish and cats idioms are surely not directly translatable into Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

> Tener otras cosas que hacer
>
> Tener cosas más importantes que hacer

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! We're all glad you're here. This isn't a bad answer, but it could be improved with some additional explanation.